# How do you add a root view controller to macOS programmatically?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I am trying to figure out how to set a root view controller on macOS. It is a bit confusing and I am getting a bit of errors as well. I did follow some iOS guidelines and try to look at some other posts about the Mac guidelines. But I am dealing with these errors. In Info.plist, I also have my main storyboard file set to "Main", should I remove that? I am new to the macOS side of things.

I am using AppKit instead of Apple's latest SwiftUI library. So this is something I am dealing with. I'd greatly appreciate anyone who offers to help! :)

Here is my AppDelegate file.

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

var window: NSWindow?


func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    
    let storyBoard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("Main"), bundle: Bundle.main)
    let homeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("ViewController")) as! ViewController
    NSApp.keyWindow?.contentViewController = homeViewController
    
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}


}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
2020-11-06 01:24:11.985119-0800 avengers[53735:1621559] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600002a0f940 "NSTextView:0x7fecb041f8b0.centerX"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600002a0c040 "NSView:0x7fecb0609d80.centerX"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.
```

`2020-11-06 01:24:12.028071-0800 avengers[53735:1621559] Storyboard (<NSStoryboard:0x600003d08320 path='/Users/jazilzaim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/avengers-gixxxwjnvqcwkreksxccdalagqme/Build/Products/Debug/avengers.app/Contents/Resources/Base.lproj/Main.storyboardc', initialController='NSWindowController-B8D-0N-5wS'>) doesn't contain a controller with identifier 'ViewController'`

This is my View Controller.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

let labelTxt: NSText = {
    let text = NSText()
    text.string = "Hello"
    text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return text
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    
    labelTxt.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    labelTxt.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    labelTxt.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
    self.view.addSubview(labelTxt)
    
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You programmatically create the vc so replace

```
let storyBoard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("Main"), bundle: Bundle.main)
let homeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("ViewController")) as! ViewController
```

with

```
let homeViewController = ViewController()
```

Also you should add the subview before making the constraints

```
self.view.addSubview(labelTxt)
labelTxt.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
labelTxt.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
labelTxt.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
```